# Why are my text elements always 100%? | CSS

Tags: html, css, width

```
<p class="main-title">text here</p>
```

So, my error is, that this simple line of code always gets 100% width for no reason. The same is for all my text elements. The Container it is in hasnt got any display state (so block) that could make the error.

If I set the width to like 150px there is something like margin still there.

Thanks for your help

Comment: more details, css and a screenshot would be great. are you able to see it with devTool what is happening?

Comment: I would like some context

Comment: Create a plnkr for us to take a look at.

Comment: My parent is position: absolute, does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will display the `p` element as block. And block elements, by default, don't stack on the same line than others.

So even if you put it at width 150px, the next element will always go next line.

To solve it either :

- display your `p` as [inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) (or just inline if you don't need to resize it)
- replace your `p` with `span`
- use [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to ask that your blocks stop pushing others

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help ! Don't forget to [mark my answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow) for others.